# I can't show image in webview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, webview, android-webview

iam use xml parser, my problem can't show imageURL  on webview. Data in webview get from listview, but in listview can show image url

this is my code in webview

```
 static final String KEY_HEADLINE = "Headline";
 static final String KEY_ARTICLEDATE = "ArticleDate";
 static final String KEY_BODY = "Body";
 static final String KEY_IMAGEURL = "ImageURL";
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.webnews);

// getting intent data
Intent in = getIntent();
Bundle bun = in.getExtras();

 //Get XML values from previous intent
String headline = bun.getString(KEY_HEADLINE);
String date = bun.getString(KEY_ARTICLEDATE);
String Body = bun.getString(KEY_BODY);
String image = bun.getString(KEY_IMAGEURL);


Log.i("Result "+KEY_HEADLINE, headline);
WebView browser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
String HTML = "<div style='margin-top:5px; margin-left:5px; margin-right:5px;margin-  bottom;5px;'></div>
<div  style='font-family:Arial;font-size:14px;fontcolor:gray;'>"+date+"</div><div><strong style='font-family:Arial; font-size:24; margin-bottom:5;'>"+headline+"</strong></div>
<div><div style='float: margin-left:2px ;margin-right: 2px;margin-bottom: 1px; margin-top: 25px;'><center><img src="+image+" alt='' style='width:200px; height:127px; margin-bottom:20px;'</center></div>
<div style='line-height: 20px;font-size:16px; font-family:Arial'>"+Body+"</div></div></div>" ;
browser.loadData(HTML, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Comment: u need to encode ur image in src tag in html and then display in webview

Answer (score 0):

webview accepts html components :
so it should be some thing like this :

```
<html>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="monika.gif" width="50px" alt="Hello">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</html>
```

Comment: my image from xml parser not local

Comment: cool then what u need to do is u hv to make a string and put all the above html contain above and need to chnage the image name and display it thats all